# Is it possible to get a variable from a remote host for a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Now I have some lines like this at the beginning of the Dockerfile:

```
ARG NPM_VERSION=6.9.0
```

But I'd like to get that value from a remote host (production or dev server for example) directly, without any human change.

Is it possible? Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the value at build time using [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables):

```
docker build -t your-image --build-arg "NPM_VERSION=$(curl https://example.com)" .
```

If that is not possible for you then you need to override the variable from within your Dockerfile within the `RUN` command that uses the variable (dynamic variables cannot be passed along the stages):

```
RUN NPM_VERSION=$(curl https://example.com) \
&&  echo $NPM_VERSION
```